# Javascript iterating nested loops and returning specific values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am very new to Javascript and trying to print out a selected teams NFL schedule.  I have created and populated a drop down menu with all the teams.  I want the user to be able to select their team and see their schedule.  I am able to return the whole list (every game), but I cannot figure out how to only return the games of the selected team.  Here is what the data looks like that I am using.

```
"Schedule": [
    {
      "gameId": "1",
      "gameWeek": "1",
      "gameDate": "2018-09-06",
      "awayTeam": "ATL",
      "homeTeam": "PHI",
      "gameTimeET": "8:20 PM",
      "tvStation": "NBC",
      "winner": "PHI"
    },
    {
      "gameId": "2",
      "gameWeek": "1",
      "gameDate": "2018-09-09",
      "awayTeam": "BUF",
      "homeTeam": "BAL",
      "gameTimeET": "1:00 PM",
      "tvStation": "CBS",
      "winner": "BAL"
```

Here is the code that returned my all the games.

```
function processData(data){

  schedule = data["Schedule"];

  for(eachGame in schedule){
    var game = schedule[eachGame];
    var week = game["gameWeek"];
    var homeTeam = game["homeTeam"];
    var awayTeam = game["awayTeam"];
    var winner = game["winner"];
    var tableRow = "<tr><td>" + week + "</td><td>" + homeTeam + "</td><td>" + awayTeam + "</td><td>" + winner + "</td></tr>";
    $("#output").append(tableRow);

  }
}
```

I need to return when the awayTeam or homeTeam are the team that the user selected.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you get which team the user selected?

Comment: let team = $('#teamSelect').val();

Comment: You could use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do that. `let teamSchedule = schedule.filter(g => g.homeTeam === team || g.awayTeam === team);`  I'm not submitting this as an answer because I feel that this question is likely a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

To reduce an array down to only a handful of its items, I'd almost always suggest using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), however I'm actually going to present an alternative solution first in your case.

If you were to use `filter` to loop through the items and find the ones you want, and then use a `for` loop to append them to the table, you'd be looping through some of  the same elements twice.

Instead, we can apply our logic to skip the games we don't want *inside the same loop*, by doing something like this:

```
//If "team" is neither the away team, nor the home team, skip this game
if (![game.awayTeam, game.homeTeam].includes(team)) return;
```

**Example 1:** (Comments added)

```js
var data = { Schedule: [{ awayTeam: "Jets", homeTeam: "Bills", winner: "Bills", week: 1 }, { awayTeam: "Saints", homeTeam: "Cardinals", winner: "Cardinals", week: 1 }, { awayTeam: "Giants", homeTeam: "Bengals", winner: "Bengals", week: 2 }, { awayTeam: "Bills", homeTeam: "Jaguars", winner: "Bills", week: 2 }, { awayTeam: "Bills", homeTeam: "Patriots", winner: "Patriots", week: 3 } ] };

function setScheduleByTeam(team) {
  let schedule = data["Schedule"];    //Get the schedule
  var $outputTable = $("#output");    //Store the table as a variable
  $outputTable.find("tbody").empty(); //Empty out the current records

  schedule.forEach(function(game) {                             //For each game in the schedule
    if (![game.awayTeam, game.homeTeam].includes(team)) return; //Skip the record if our team isn't in it

    //Create + Append table row
    var tableRow = "<tr><td>" + game.week + "</td><td>" + game.homeTeam + "</td><td>" + game.awayTeam + "</td><td>" + game.winner + "</td></tr>";
    $outputTable.append(tableRow);
  });
}

//On button click
$("body").on("click", "button", function() {
  let team = $('#teamSelect').val();  //Get selected team
  setScheduleByTeam(team);            //Update the table to that team's schedule
});
```

```css
td,th { padding: 5px 15px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="teamSelect">
  <option>Select Team</option>
  <option value="Bengals">Bengals</option>
  <option value="Bills">Bills</option>
  <option value="Jets">Jets</option>
</select>
<button>Go!</button>

<table id="output">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Week</th>
      <th>Home</th>
      <th>Away</th>
      <th>Winner</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

However, some might argue for cleanliness, in which case I'd suggest going with the `filter` method I mentioned earlier:

**Example 2** (Comments added)

```js
var data = { Schedule: [{ awayTeam: "Jets", homeTeam: "Bills", winner: "Bills", week: 1 }, { awayTeam: "Saints", homeTeam: "Cardinals", winner: "Cardinals", week: 1 }, { awayTeam: "Giants", homeTeam: "Bengals", winner: "Bengals", week: 2 }, { awayTeam: "Bills", homeTeam: "Jaguars", winner: "Bills", week: 2 }, { awayTeam: "Bills", homeTeam: "Patriots", winner: "Patriots", week: 3 } ] };

//Filter out schedule to only games where awayTeam == team OR homeTeam == team.
//Returns the filtered team's schedule
const getGamesByTeam = (team) => data.Schedule.filter(g => g.awayTeam == team || g.homeTeam == team);

function updateScheduleTable(games) {  
  var $outputTable = $("#output");     //Store table as variable
  $outputTable.find("tbody").empty();  //Remove existing rows
  
  games.forEach(function(game) {  //For each game, append to table
    var tableRow = "<tr><td>" + game.week + "</td><td>" + game.homeTeam + "</td><td>" + game.awayTeam + "</td><td>" + game.winner + "</td></tr>";
    $outputTable.append(tableRow);
  });
  
}

$("body").on("click", "button", function() {
  let team = $('#teamSelect').val();  //Get the selected team
  let games = getGamesByTeam(team);   //Get a filtered array of one team's schedule
  updateScheduleTable(games);         //Update the table based on that set of games
});
```

```css
td,th { padding: 5px 15px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="teamSelect">
  <option>Select Team</option>
  <option value="Bengals">Bengals</option>
  <option value="Bills">Bills</option>
  <option value="Jets">Jets</option>
</select>
<button>Go!</button>

<table id="output">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Week</th>
      <th>Home</th>
      <th>Away</th>
      <th>Winner</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort your array of data based on the user's selected team. To do that, you need to use an [array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to loop over the array and return values based on logic you put in the loop. To do this, I used the `reduce` method (IMO the most useful array method).

```
function filterForSelectedTeam(data) {
  const accumulator = [];
  const team = $('#teamSelect').val();
  const schedule = data["Schedule"];
  // if team has a value this reduce method will return a sorted array
  // based on the logic in the loop.
  return team && schedule.reduce((acc, game) => {
    if (game["homeTeam"] === team || game['awayTeam'] === team) {
      acc.push(game);
    };
    return acc;
  }, accumulator);
}

const data = [] // your data here;
const gamesBySelectedTeam = filterForSelectedTeam(data)

gamesBySelectedTeam.forEach(game => {
  const tableRow = "<tr><td>" + game['gameWeek'] + "</td><td>" + game['homeTeam'] + "</td><td>" + game['awayTeam'] + "</td><td>" + game['winner'] + "</td></tr>";
  $("#output").append(tableRow);
});
```

Comment: While `reduce` is great if you're trying to go from many-to-one, if you're just looking to filter an array, it's much easier and cleaner to use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). That said, the optimal solution would probably just be to include the "Should I display this game?" logic inside the `forEach`, that way you can use one loop instead of two :)

Comment: @TylerRoper, you should provide your own solution with the filter method to show how much "cleaner and easier" it is. Also, I wouldn't just shove all the logic into a forEach loop. I wanna show the reduction so it is easier to read for other developers. If anything I should chain the two loops.

Comment: It was merely a piece of advice. It seems you've chosen to take it as an attack instead. Not to mention, I wrote a one-line filter method in the comments above a few minutes before you submitted your answer.

Comment: @TylerRoper didn't take it as an attack. I'm just pointing out that if you have a better solution, you should provide it. That's kinda the whole point of SO.

Comment: @TylerRoper, it's just a different way of thinking that is all. I usually use `reduce` instead of `map` or `filter` because it accomplishes the same goals and you can also return different types. I appreciate your help man.

Comment: No hard feelings :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this with just a few method calls:

```
function processData({ Schedule: s }, team) {
  // s is now the equivolent of data['Schedule']
  // Filter the data to get all games where either
  // the away of home team is the team sent in
  // Empty the table so it includes only those games appended below
  // Append the array of games as html elements
  $("#output")empty().append(
    s.filter(g => g.awayTeam === team || g.homeTeam === team)
    .map(g => {
      `<tr>
        <td>${game.gameWeek}</td>
        <td>${game.homeTeam}</td>
        <td>${game.awayTeam}</td>
        <td>${game.winner}</td>
      </tr>`
    })
  );
}
```

You can append an array of html strings to the DOM and they get handled properly.